# A connected, but not path-connected, space whose fundamental group depends on the basepoint

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

It is a well known result that the fundamental group of a path-connected space is independent (up to isomorphism) of the choice of the basepoint.
Can someone provide an explicit example of a connected, but not path-connected, space for which the fundamental group does indeed depend on the basepoint?

Comment: How about sticking a loop onto the end of the topologist's sine curve?

Comment: The fundamental group is entirely about maps from paths into your space, so it would be ridiculous if it could detect things in different path-components. Generalizing Lord Shark's example, call the "path disconnected wedge" (a name I  made up for an operation I made up) of two pointed spaces $X$ and $Y$ to be what you get when you take the topologist's sine curve (with the arc at the end), reflecting it across the $y$-axis, and gluing the two spaces to the two 'endpoints' of this connected but not path-connected, 'arc'. Then the f.g. of the $X$ component is $\pi_1 X$, and similarly with $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = \{(\sin(t), \cos(t), \arctan(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid  t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then let $Y = S^1 \times \{-\pi/4\}$ and $Z = (S^1 \times \{\pi/4\})\vee W$ for any path-connected space $W$ with non-trivial fundamental group.

Now take the space $X \cup Y \cup Z$ which is connected ($X$ gets arbitrarily close to both $Y$ and $Z$ and so cannot be separated from either by open neighbourhoods), but has three distinct path-components, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, with $\pi_1(X) = 1$, $\pi_1(Y) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(Z) =\mathbb{Z} \ast \pi_1(W)$ which are each non-isomorphic.