# Are all elements of an abelian fundamental group path homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups, fundamental-groups, path-connected

Consider the fundamental group of some topological space $X$. Is it true that if this group is abelian, then all elements are necessarily path homotopic?

Comment: Are you asking about general topological groups that are abelian, or about topological spaces whose fundamental groups are abelian?

Comment: @hardmath Topological spaces whose fundamental groups are abelian

Comment: Are you asking if $X$ is path connected whenever $\pi_1 X$ is abelian? Or if $\pi_1 X$ is itself path connected in some topology (probably inherited from $X$ somehow)?

Comment: Ah - I see there was some overlap in questions. That answers mine too

Comment: @HallaSurvivor The former, if the fundamental group of some topological space is abelian then it is path homotopic.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly silly answer:

Remember the fundamental group relies on a choice of basepoint. So if you take any disconnected space (in particular not path connected) "the" fundamental group will only refer to one of the components. And thus can be abelian when the space is disconnected.

This is one place where the fundamental groupoid begins to look more appealing, as the fundamental groupoid of a disjoint union of spaces is the disjoint union of the groupoids.

---

For a less silly example, you can run the same argument as outlined in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074960/a-connected-but-not-path-connected-space-whose-fundamental-group-depends-on-th). But take $W$ to be your favorite path connected space with a trivial fundamental group.

Again, this relies on the fact that you need a choice of basepoint. But this isn't really cheating, because the fundamental group *can't* detect things in other path components (since it's constructed with paths). So any counterexample to claims involving path-disconnected spaces will need to be at least a little bit silly in this way.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer, though I apologize as after submitting my question I realized my sleep-deprived self had written path-connected instead of path-homotopic. I have edited the question, sorry once again!

Comment: What do you mean by two loops being path homotopic? I'm not sure if I've seen this before, and a quick google only brings up the notion of a homotopy between paths.

Comment: It is a homotopy of paths that preserves beginning and end points

Comment: Then two loops are homotopic if and only if they are the same element in the fundamental group. So as long as your fundamental group isn't trivial, you can have two loops that aren't path homotopic.

Comment: Consider the circle, whose fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian. Then the "do nothing" path and the path which wraps around the circle once are not homotopic.

Comment: I can add this to my answer in an edit if you'd like

Comment: Wouldn't the example you gave be path homotopic?

Comment: No - two loops are homotopic (preserving the base point) if and only if they are the same element of the fundamental group. Since $1 \neq 0$, the two loops cannot be homotopic